# input, onchange event dont fire when value is set manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I want to catch the event on the range slider even if i press a button and change the Value by:

```
$("input").val(1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BaEar/188/

But the event "input" dont fire by button press. And "change" is also not working.

HTML:

```
<input type="range">
<button>Change</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("input").on("input", function() { //Does not fire on button click :(
    $("#output").text($(this).val());
});

$("button").click(function() {
   $("input").val(1); 
});
```

Anyone with a solution ? Thanks :)

Comment: Programatically changing a value does not fire the native events, as it would be a major inconveniance in some instances. You have to trigger the event handler yourself when changing the value, as in `$("input").val(1).trigger('input');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, change the `on` handler to use `change` like

```
$("input").on("change", function() { 
    $("#output").text($(this).val());
});
```

Second, manually trigger it in the click handler like

```
$("button").click(function() {
   $("input").val(1); 
    $("input").trigger("change");
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BaEar/190/)

Comment: Thanks. thats some workaround. And it works. Why does the event not trigger? even the gui changes... strange

Comment: @Cracker0dks, like adeneo said, when you programmatically change an input, you need to trigger there associated events manually

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("input").on("input change", function() {
    $("#output").text($(this).val());
});

$("button").click(function() {
   $("input").val(1);
   $("input").change();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BaEar/192/

So the range slider is normally updating by changing the value. AmmarCSE solution only triggers, if a value is set.

Answer (score 1):

I think `$("input").val(1)` should be changed to `$("input").val(1).trigger('input');`. You are listening for `input` event so after changing the value that event should be fired.

jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/BaEar/191/

Comment: Nice, I had no idea an 'input' event even existed :)