# Event when input value is changed by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, events

What is the event when an `<input>` element's value is changed via JavaScript code? For example:

```
$input.value = 12;
```

The `input` event is not helping here because it's not the user who is changing the value.

When testing on Chrome, the `change` event isn't fired. Maybe because the element didn't lose focus (it didn't gain focus, so it can't lose it)?

Comment: There is no event when the value is changed by Javascript.

Comment: @Kinduser no...

Comment: While there are some exceptions, events are mostly fired only due to external actions that affect the browser, not from Javascript code.

Comment: @Kinduser "No" is the full answer.

Comment: I can't seem to locate a non jQuery duplicate such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291801/input-onchange-event-dont-fire-when-value-is-set-manually

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on @t-j-crowder and @maciej-swist answers, let's add this one, with ".apply" function that prevent infinite loop without redefining the object.

```
 function customInputSetter(){

  var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value");
  var originalSet = descriptor.set;

  // define our own setter
  descriptor.set = function(val) {
    console.log("Value set", this, val);
    originalSet.apply(this,arguments);
  }

  Object.defineProperty(HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value", descriptor);
}
```

Answer (score 19):

There is no built-in event for that. You have at least four choices:

1. Any time you change `$input.value` in code, call the code you want triggered by the change
2. Poll for changes
3. Give yourself a method you use to change the value, which will also do notifications
4. (Variant of #3) Give yourself a *property* you use to change the value, which will also do notifications

Of those, you'll note that #1, #3, and #4 all require that you do something in your code differently from just `$input.value = "new value";` Polling, option #2, is the only one that will work with code that just sets `value` directly.

Details:

1. The simplest solution: Any time you change `$input.value` in code, call the code you want triggered by the change:

   ```
   $input.value = "new value";
   handleValueChange();
   ```
2. Poll for changes:

   ```
   var last$inputValue = $input.value;
   setInterval(function() {
       var newValue = $input.value;
       if (last$inputValue != newValue) {
           last$inputValue = newValue;
           handleValueChange();
       }
   }, 50); // 20 times/second
   ```

   Polling has a bad reputation (for good reasons), because it's a constant CPU consumer. Modern browsers dial down timer events (or even bring them to a stop) when the tab doesn't have focus, which mitigates that a bit. 20 times/second isn't an issue on modern systems, even mobiles.

   But still, polling is an ugly last resort.

   Example:

   ```js
   var $input = document.getElementById("$input");
   var last$inputValue = $input.value;
   setInterval(function() {
       var newValue = $input.value;
       if (last$inputValue != newValue) {
           last$inputValue = newValue;
           handleValueChange();
       }
   }, 50); // 20 times/second
   function handleValueChange() {
       console.log("$input's value changed: " + $input.value);
   }
   // Trigger a change
   setTimeout(function() {
       $input.value = "new value";
   }, 800);
   ```

   ```html
   <input type="text" id="$input">
   ```
3. Give yourself a function to set the value and notify you, and use that function instead of `value`, combined with an `input` event handler to catch changes by users:

   ```
   $input.setValue = function(newValue) {
       this.value = newValue;
       handleValueChange();
   };
   $input.addEventListener("input", handleValueChange, false);
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   $input.setValue("new value");
   ```

   Naturally, you have to remember to use `setValue` instead of assigning to `value`.

   Example:

   ```js
   var $input = document.getElementById("$input");
   $input.setValue = function(newValue) {
       this.value = newValue;
       handleValueChange();
   };
   $input.addEventListener("input", handleValueChange, false);
   function handleValueChange() {
       console.log("$input's value changed: " + $input.value);
   }
   // Trigger a change
   setTimeout(function() {
       $input.setValue("new value");
   }, 800);
   ```

   ```html
   <input type="text" id="$input">
   ```
4. A variant on #3: Give yourself a different *property* you can set (again combined with an event handler for user changes):

   ```
   Object.defineProperty($input, "val", {
       get: function() {
           return this.value;
       },
       set: function(newValue) {
           this.value = newValue;
           handleValueChange();
       }
   });
   $input.addEventListener("input", handleValueChange, false);
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   $input.val = "new value";
   ```

   This works in all modern browsers, even old Android, and even IE8 (which supports `defineProperty` on DOM elements, but not JavaScript objects in general). Of course, you'd need to test it on your target browsers.

   But `$input.val = ...` looks like an error to anyone used to reading normal DOM code (or jQuery code).

   Before you ask: No, you can't use the above to replace the `value` property itself.

   Example:

   ```js
   var $input = document.getElementById("$input");
   Object.defineProperty($input, "val", {
       get: function() {
           return this.value;
       },
       set: function(newValue) {
           this.value = newValue;
           handleValueChange();
       }
   });
   $input.addEventListener("input", handleValueChange, false);
   function handleValueChange() {
       console.log("$input's value changed: " + $input.value);
   }
   // Trigger a change
   setTimeout(function() {
       $input.val = "new value";
   }, 800);
   ```

   ```html
   <input type="text" id="$input">
   ```

Answer (score 7):

I'd add a 5th option based on T.J. Crowder suggestions.
But instead of adding new property You could change the actual "value" property to trigger additional action when set - either for the specific input element, or for all input objects:

```
//First store the initial descriptor of the "value" property:

var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value");
var inputSetter = descriptor.set;

//Then modify the "setter" of the value to notify when the value is changed:

descriptor.set = function(val) {

    //changing to native setter to prevent the loop while setting the value
    Object.defineProperty(this, "value", {set:inputSetter});
    this.value = val;

    //Custom code triggered when $input.value is set
    console.log("Value set: "+val);

    //changing back to custom setter
    Object.defineProperty(this, "value", descriptor);   
}

//Last add the new "value" descriptor to the $input element
Object.defineProperty($input, "value", descriptor);
```

Instead of changing the "value" property for specific input element, it can be changed generically for all input elements:

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value", descriptor);
```

This method works only for change of value with javascript e.g. input.value="new value". It doesn't work when keying in the new value in the input box.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution to hook the value property changed for all inputs:

```
var valueDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value");

HTMLInputElement.prototype.addInputChangedByJsListener = function(cb) {
    if(!this.hasOwnProperty("_inputChangedByJSListeners")) {
        this._inputChangedByJSListeners = [];
    }
    this._inputChangedByJSListeners.push(cb);
}

Object.defineProperty(HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value", {
    get: function() {
        return valueDescriptor.get.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    set: function() {
        var self = this;
        valueDescriptor.set.apply(self, arguments);
        if(this.hasOwnProperty("_inputChangedByJSListeners")){
            this._inputChangedByJSListeners.forEach(function(cb) {
                cb.apply(self);
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Usage example:

```
document.getElementById("myInput").addInputChangedByJsListener(function() {
    console.log("Input changed to \"" + this.value + "\"");
});
```

Comment: Smart and hacky, I like it, just make sure to only use this while debugging :)

Answer (score 5):

One possible strategy is to use a [mutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect changes in attributes as follows:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
          mutations.forEach(function(){
                 console.log('hello')});
          });

          observer.observe($input, {
                 attributes: true
          });
```

Although this in itself will not detect a change like:

```
$input.value = 12
```

it WILL detect a change of the actual value attribute:

```
$input.setAttribute('value', 12)
```

So if it is you that is setting the value programatically, just be sure to alter the attribute alongside the `value = 12` statement and you can have the desired result.

Comment: that is a very fancy solution. actually I need reflect external change so that not helping me . but it still very nice solution

Comment: This does work on chrome and firefox. They seem to change the value in the dom also!

Answer (score 4):

A simple way is just to trigger an input event when you change the value.

You can do this in plain javascript.

Early in your script, put something like this:

```
let inputEvent = new Event('input',{bubbles:true,cancelable: true});
```

You can change 'input' to the event you want, 'change', 'blur', etc

Then, any time you change a value, just call this event on the same element

```
input.value = 12;// <- your example
input.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);// <- calling an event
```

This is vanilla javascript

Comment: the all point is that the third party changed the value not me, but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an event that will cover all the programatically assigned scenarios for an input. But, I can tell you that you can programatically "fire" an event (a custom event, a regular event or just trigger an event handler[s])

It appears to me that you're using jQuery, and so, you could use:

```
$('input#inputId').val('my new value...').triggerHandler('change');
```

In that example, you're assigning a value, and forcing a call to the handler (or handlers) binded with the "change" event.

Answer (score 1):

> Event when input value is changed by JavaScript?

We can use event triggering with [target.dispashEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent), as explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript).

Example with a text input:

```
const input = document.querySelector('.myTextInput'); 
    
//Create the appropriate event according to needs
const change = new InputEvent('change');
  
//Change the input value
input.value = 'new value';

//Fire the event;
const isNotCancelled = input.dispatchEvent(change);
```

When any handler on that event type doesn't use `event.preventDefault()`, `isNotCancelled` will be `true`, otherwise, it will be `false`.

Comment: that nice answer can combine with the Correct one. to trigger input events even when input is changed by code.  by stand-alone it not answer the question because the event not fire by himself  wathever the value changed somewhere ( maybe by third party code )