# addEventListener does not appear to work for change event

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Just a simple js snippet:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="t1">
<input type="text" id="t2">
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var t1 = document.getElementById('t1');
var t2 = document.getElementById('t2');

t1.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    t2.value = t1.value.toUpperCase();
});

t2.addEventListener('change propertychange input', function () {
    alert('dd');
});
```

As you can see, t2's change event never triggered! this is pretty simple and no need more description. Tested out in 'Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)' and 'Firefox 52.0(32-bit)'. Does anyone have any idea?

UPDATE:

It should be like this about t2.addEventListener:

```
t2.addEventListener('change', function () {
    alert('dd');
});
```

OR

```
$("#t2").on('change propertychange input',function(){
    // do something here......
});
```

UPDATE AGAIN:

Actually, there is no t1 typing or changing event. I'm using this just for a sample. the only thing I want is I need to know when the t2's value changed by another functions. So, I think we should focus on t2, not t1.

UPDATE THREE:

I believe that all you guys used Google autocomplete before. some snippet likes this:

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    // .......
);
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);

function fillInAddress(){
    t2.val(......);
}
```

But, the thing is, I don't want put the trigger thing in 'fillInAddress', instead, I want capture this changed event in addEventListener or on('change') on t2, just like I wrote before ...

FINAL UPDATE:

Still can't figure out why t2 'change' event can not be triggered. However, I put something in t1 just like @Kind user did and the problem resolved. If anyone have any ideas, I'm very appreciate if you would share with me!

Comment: Duplicate of [*what is the event when input value changed by javascript*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427606/what-is-the-event-when-input-value-changed-by-javascript). I've posted an [answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43272514/157247).

Answer (score 2):

In my honest opinion, I bet that OP actually desires the `alert` to fire if the `t2` input value change was caused by change of the `t1` input.

**Note**: For this moment, it's a `jQuery` solution.

```js
$('#t1').on('keyup', function() {
  $('#t2').val($(this).val().toUpperCase()).change();
});

$('#t2').on('change', function() {
  alert('dd');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="t1">
<input type="text" id="t2">
```

Comment: thanks, you are almost there!  the only thing different is actually there is no t1 typing or changing event we can use. I'm using this just for a sample. But yes, like you said, the only thing what I want is I need to know when the t2's value changed by another functions.

Comment: Well, now I wish it would let me undo my upvote on the other answer. This is the correct answer. @Jackzhao As long as the value is updated using `.val` or [you manually trigger the event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250464/trigger-change-event-when-the-input-value-changed-programatically) then it should work as expected.

Comment: @Jackzhao: *"like you said, the only thing what I want is I need to know when the t2's value changed by another functions"* That completely changes your question. Your question didn't say you wanted to detect changes made **by code**. Changed  by other code *in general*, or specifically when `t1`'s event handler changes it? The above will do the latter (though I would recommend not doing it that way, through a synthetic event), but not the former.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder TJ, I'm willing to upvote your answer immediately if you would provide a pure js solution on OP problem.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You are right, didn't think that much, my bad!  but I'm still stuck here.....

Comment: @Jackzhao: Are you still stuck? You've accepted this answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yes, I still don't know why the t2.val() changed event  can not 
 be detected. it supposed to be a very simple feature! Like I said in the FINAL UPDATE, hope someone like you can share with me another experience.

Comment: @Jackzhao It's kinda extraordinary and not that simple feature as you would think. Everything is clear if the value of the input changes by typing on the keyboard, because pressing keyboard keys is an event itself. In your particular case, you don't know the events or you just don't want to use the `change` function which would *alert* the system that the value of the input has been changed. Javascript can't just observe and listen to very each element/input and so on in the document, because it would be basically an overkill. That's why we use events to listen to specified modifications.

Comment: @Kinduser: I totally understand, and some people says 'direct assignation of values does not trigger any DOM event'. but, I still want to try for a few days. there must be something or somewhere wrong!
Btw, THANK YOU.