# Why is a password value initialized though there is no function doing it?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I've just rebuilt the full script and php of a user profile.

When the page loads, surname, forename, email etc. must be initialized.

Currently I have functions initializing all fields EXCEPT the password.

And for some reason, it is still initialized.

The markup for the password element looks like this:

```html
<input id= "password" type = "password" class = "form-control changeable">
   <span id = "changeType" class = "input-group-addon">
     <i class = "glyphicon glyphicon-random"></i>
   </span>
</input>
```

There really is no single function in the whole script/front-end addressing this element.

As far as I know there also aren't any processes not located on this site which could interfere.

So I'd like to ask: 
Is it possible that there is some browserroutine doing this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "initialized"? Do you mean, populated with a value, or something like that?

Comment: yes, populated with a value. The value is made to "dots" although you can still read out the value with console.log.

Comment: Well, *something*'s changing it - you might attach a listener and use `debugger`

Comment: what kind of listener do I have to implement? I mean, an onchange which fires doesn't do much by itself, how can I track the source of the input?

Comment: Ah, nm, it's harder than I thought, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427606/event-when-input-value-is-changed-by-javascript

Comment: One *nasty* solution would be to overwrite `HTMLInputElement.prototype.value` setter with your own method that checks whether `this` is the `#password` element you're interested in :P (only use that strategy for debugging) edit: oh, the question I linked to even has that as one of the answers already

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the reason:
It was indeed autofill.

I have no idea why it did. In no way was the site configured to interact with firefoxs autofill. However, deleting my firefoxprofile granted me the opportunity to enter the site without any saved userdata, and there I saw that the password was indeed filled by the browser since it wasn't populated this time.