# How to limit textarea maxlength when adding data on button click event?

Tags: javascript, html

I am performing the following steps:
1- A textarea whose maxlength is 50.
2- A button on click of which text is getting appended to textarea.

> Issue: Maxlength validation does not work if keep clicking the button.
>   Don't want to put any check of maxlength on button click.

Is there any textArea eventlistener I can add to put a check if adding data on button click event.

```
<body>
    <textarea id="test" rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="50">
    </textarea>

    <button onclick="appendData()"> Click </button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
            var txtArea = document.querySelector('textarea');
        });

        document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
            alert('inside event listener of textarea 2')
        })

        function appendData(){
            document.querySelector('textarea').value += "hello";
        }

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: you can get the value before appending text into it

Comment: Why do you not want to add a check in the button click handler?

Comment: @user4520 Thanks for the response. I cannot add check in the click handler of button because it's a part of reusable component and I cannot add a specific functionality to common component. Is there no such event of textArea?

Comment: @mkamranhamid you mean to say that in click handler of button I can get the value of textArea? Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event when input value is changed by JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427606/event-when-input-value-is-changed-by-javascript) even though this question is about `<textarea>` it's about the same problem..

Comment: @walter Can you add your own click handler instead of the existing one which you don't want to update ?

Answer (score 0):

Any specific reason why you don't want to check/do this in the onclick javascript ? I think there is no such TextArea eventListener which can be used to accomplish this. Other keyboard (onKeyUp, onKeyDown or onKeyPress Events) events can't be used since the value is directly set into the input element (which I believe clients would be using to implement the maxLength functionality when a key is pressed on the keyboard).

This can be done with the size check in the onclick javascript before setting the new value in the textarea.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function hello() {
     var ta = document.getElementById("test"),
         maxlength = ta.maxLength,
         value = ta.value,
         textToAppend = "hello";

     value += "hello";
     totalLen = value.length;
     if (totalLen>maxlength) {
         return false;
     }
     else {
         ta.value = value;
         return true;
     }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea id="test" rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="50">
  </textarea>
  <button onclick="hello();"> Click </button>
</body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w872cva6/)

This code can be improved to append only a substring if the maxLength check fails only after appending the full string.

Comment: In the comments the questioner mentions `"I cannot add check in the click"`

Comment: @caramba Yes, saw this after posting my answer. Thanks.