# Value gets copied when entered manually, but not automatically on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Two fields `input1` and `input2` gives a total sum to `input3` on click and it needs to be copied to the next `input4` field, but it doesn't.

Although if you enter the value to `input3` manually then it gets copied? (it actually doesn't get copied live until you click e.g. tab or click anywhere with the mouse, also don't know how to resolve)

Full code https://jsfiddle.net/tn6wr4xc/1/

So basically when you click the first `Sum` button it should copy the value to the `input4`, but it doesn't, only when entered manually.

Sorry for ghetto code, I know it's vanilla and jQuery, real beginner here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use *input* event to make the immediate changes to output the result.

***I will think of the solution in a different approach than yours.***

First you can target all the inputs with class *formA* and *formB* using [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Then loop through them to attach the event (*input*) using [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Inside the event handler function you can target only specific inputs related to the current element. You can find the sum of them using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Finally store the sum in the relevant element.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.formA, .formB');

Array.from(inputs).forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('input', function(){
    var group = this.closest('div').querySelectorAll('[class^=form]');
    var sum = Array.from(group).map(i => Number(i.value)).reduce((a,c) => a+c,0);
    this.closest('div').querySelector('[name=total]').value = sum;
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="forms">
  <div class="form-a">
    <p>Form A</p>
    input1 : <input class="formA form-1" type="text" name="qty1"/><br>
    input2 : <input class="formA form-2" type="text" name="qty2"/><br>
    input3 (total) : <input class="total-1" type="text" name="total" id="total"/>
  </div>
  <hr>

  <div class="form-b">
    <p>Form B</p>
    input4 : <input class="formB form-3" type="text" name="qty3"/><br>
    input5 : <input class="formB form-4" type="text" name="qty4"/><br>
    input6 (total) : <input type="text" name="total" id="total2"/>
  </div>
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do it by that way because you update the value property by JavaScript which is not "**by a user**" so the event is not fired as desired.

But in order to achieve what you wanted, you can look through [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427606/event-when-input-value-is-changed-by-javascript). They describe many ways to overcome the problem. And then one of the most common is to directly modify the **input4 value** after the you have modify the **input3 one** by this way 

`...
result.value = sum;
$('.form-3').val(sum);`