# Listen to changes to an input field done by another (inaccessible) javascript code

Tags: javascript

Appreciate this is a very specific question and in part addressed in places like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431337/sending-message-to-chrome-extension-from-a-web-page/11431812#11431812) however does not fit the purpose. Essentially I am utilising a form tool (frevvo) which allows for stripped back javascript where 90% of things are done. This stripped back javascript alters an input field which works fine.

The challenge comes when trying to listen to that change on the page through (full) javascript (outside the stipped back JS) through the standard means (i.e. browser/extension/console etc) -> el.addEventListener("change", (event) => {}. This naturally works for where a user alters it but not where the stripped back JS does. As it's stripped back JS i cannot for instance programmatically trigger the event listener by firing a change event so am purely restricted to identifying a change at the browser level so essentially need to agnosticially detect a change in the input field irrespective of the source of the change.

Comment: Possible dupe of - https://stackoverflow.com/q/42427606/1746830

Comment: Thanks I didn't come across this. I was trying to avoid polling which I suspect is the only option based on reading that response but will see if it works!

Comment: Good luck, Brodie :)

Comment: For anyone who comes across this; polling works even if it's ugly. I notice that there is performance delay when there's load (based on the other JS running) but this may be the same with a listener in any respect.